# Adding a logical key to a View in SQL Server Manager

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework

The .NET Entity framework is giving me the following error:

"The table/view 'Foo.dbo.vwFoo' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys and uncomment it."

The view is a collection of a variety of tables and calculations. What I'd like to do is create a "logical key" using one of the columns that I know should be unique.  I can't figure out how to do this in SQL Server Manager 2005 (not a DBA.)

Anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EF can't find the PK, because VIEWs don't have PKs. However, if the view returns a unique column, you can tell the EF that this is the "PK."

It's explained in this tip:  [How to work with Updatable Views](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx)

Comment: That link suggests modifying the SSDL.  However, the SSDL gets blown away every time you do "Update Model From Database" on the EF designer view.  So this solution is something you would need to remember to reapply every time you update your edmx from the db.