# Defining View in Entity Data Model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to add a view to an entity data model but I get the error below. 
The view is a group by with a count.  I don’t understand this because a view does not have a primary key by it’s nature.

I modified the original post because I figured out how to add a key to the view. But I still have the same problem.

> warning 6013: The table/view
>   'fmcsa.dbo.vieFMCSADocumentCount' does
>   not have a primary key defined and no
>   valid primary key could be inferred.
>   This table/view has been excluded. To
>   use the entity, you will need to
>   review your schema, add the correct
>   keys, and uncomment it.

Here is the View

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vieFMCSADocumentCount] with SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT     COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountOfDocs, ROLE_ID, OWNER_ID
FROM         dbo.FMCSA_DOCUMENT
GROUP BY ROLE_ID, OWNER_ID
```

then I can add a key

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [MainIndex] ON [dbo].[vieFMCSADocumentCount] 
(
    [OWNER_ID] ASC,
    [ROLE_ID] ASC
)
```

Still not working.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745341/can-ms-sql-views-have-primary-and-foriegn-keys) and see if it helps

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a logical key to a View in SQL Server Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368964/adding-a-logical-key-to-a-view-in-sql-server-manager)

Comment: Sorry none of these hints helped me. I don't know how to add a logical key to a View. Can one of you be more specific? Also reply as an answer instead of a comment so I can accpet the answer if it helps me.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify, but I'm assuming you're using EF4.  I've come across this before--you either want to define a key manually or edit recreate your view `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and reimport.

Schema binding effectively tells SQL to track dependencies for your view.  It's both a blessing and a curse (try adding a column to `FMCSA_DOCUMENT` once this view has schema binding), so you might want to read up on the effects.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vieFMCSADocumentCount] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
  SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CountOfDocs, ROLE_ID, OWNER_ID 
  FROM  dbo.FMCSA_DOCUMENT GROUP BY ROLE_ID, OWNER_ID
```

Alternately, in the EF Model Browser Go to the Entity Types folder,  find your view (right click and choose Show in Designer).  Then on the view, highlight the column(s) that comprise your primary key and right click and choose "Entity Key"

Comment: I thought I had this solved but I didn't, so I modified my original post.

Comment: @BoB Avallone -- after altering your view to add ScheamBinding ...did you delete and re-import the view into your EF model?  I've found the auto-synch EF tries in inaccurate/incomplete in many scenarios, particularly with key definitions.